# Не удается подобрать маску для формата строки в дату с русской локалью

Tags: python, строки, datetime

Есть строка вида `17 янв 2019 в 23:24:25`. Необходимо перевести ее в формат даты, чтобы затем рассчитать разницу между двумя датами. Не удается перевести в дату. Пробовал так:

```
from datetime import datetime

def diff_days(x, y):
    format = '%d %b %Y в %H:%M:%S'
    d1 = datetime.strptime(x, format)
    d2 = datetime.strptime(y, format)
    return d2 - d1
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
time data '17 янв 2019 в 23:24:25' does not match format '%d %b %Y в %H:%M:%S'
```

[Ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) на `datetime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime

def parse_day(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x, '%d %b %Y в %H:%M:%S')

print(locale.getlocale()) # ('Russian_Russia', '1251')
#parse_day('17 янв 2019 в 23:24:25') # Ошибка

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru') # для Windows
# locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "ru_RU") # для MacOS
print(locale.getlocale()) # ('ru_RU', 'UTF-8')
parse_day('17 янв 2019 в 23:24:25') # Нет ошибки, корректно переводит в дату
```

Answer (score 0):

Для "`янв`" должна быть русская локаль, а у вас скорее всего английская. Потому и не работает. Без костылей не решить.

Comment: `locale.getlocale()` возвращает `('Russian_Russia', '1251')`

Comment: Что делает strftime() с таким же шаблоном?

Comment: С `strftime()` ошибка `descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object`. Но мне удалось решить. Спасибо за наводку к локали. Сейчас напишу ответ.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/483072)

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics конечно же не является ответом на вопрос. Ведь вопроса-то и не было 